# Helper input numeric Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

Is there a input for only numeric text in scala?
for text I use :`@helper.inputText(field)`
And for numeric? What should I use?  How can I use mask with input in scala?
I've read the input documentation but i haven't found any thing.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something after a 1-minute google, input helpers are for generating the form, not for validating what is entered?

Comment: You should use something like: http://play-bootstrap3.herokuapp.com/docs#html5-number there you have scala templates with HTML5 validation

Answer (score -1):

Just add `'type -> "number"`

For example:

```
@helper.inputText(
    yourForm("yourFormField"),
    '_label ->"Enter a   number",
    'type -> "number"
)
```